# What's the difference between gets and scanf?

Tags: c, input, scanf, gets

If the code is

```
scanf("%s\n",message)
```

vs

```
gets(message)
```

what's the difference?It seems that both of them get input to message.

Comment: `scanf()` is Standard C and `gets()` isn't (anymore).

Comment: Is everyone neglecting to mention that `gets` is deprecated on purpose? Even answers that are 4 years old say to avoid `gets` like the plague.

Comment: @remyabel and they are also not mentioning that `scanf()` is equally unsafe... and everybody is ignoring poor `fgets()` which should be The One Way of getting user input.

Comment: Indeed... I wasn't going to answer, but after so many answers ignoring this, I felt I had to point this out.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: **If** used properly `scanf()` is perfectly safe.

Comment: @alk that's true, but using `scanf()` properly is **a lot** harder than using `fgets()` properly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The basic difference [in reference to your particular scenario],

- `scanf()` ends taking input upon encountering a `whitespace`, `newline` or `EOF`
- `gets()` considers a whitespace as a part of the input string and ends the input upon encountering `newline` or `EOF`.

However, to avoid **buffer overflow** errors and to avoid security risks, its safer to use `fgets()`.

Comment: Note: `scanf("%s\n",message)` does _not_ end taking input upon encountering a whitespace, newline.  `"%s\n"` causes `scanf()` to 1) scan in all white-space input and discard them 2) scan in all non-white-space input and save them to `message`, finally appending `'\0'` 3) scan in all white-space input and discard them until encountering a non-white-space `char`, which is put back into `stdin` for the next IO call.

Comment: @chux Thank you sir for the clarification. In my answer, by saying `taking input` i meant storing non-whitespaces into the supplied buffer `message`. However, your comment makes this answer complete.

Comment: Dear Downvoter, instead of downvote-and-run policy, if you care to leave a comment, it will help me to improve this answer (and next ones). Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Disambiguation: In the following context I'd consider "*safe*" if not leading to trouble when correctly used. And "*unsafe*" if the "unsafetyness" cannot be maneuvered around.

> ```
> scanf("%s\n",message)
> ```
>
> vs
>
> ```
> gets(message)
> ```
>
> What's the difference?

In terms of safety there is no difference, both read in from `Standard Input` and might very well overflow `message`, if the user enters more data then `message`provides memory for.

Whereas `scanf()` allows you to be used safely by specifying the maximum amount of data to be scanned in:

```
char message[42];

...

scanf("%41s", message); /* Only read in one few then the buffer (messega here) 
                           provides as one byte is necessary to store the 
                           C-"string"'s 0-terminator. */
```

With `gets()` it is  **not** possible to specify the maximum number of characters be read in, that's why the latter **shall not be used**!

Comment: scanf() is less safe than gets, because of the reduced type safety.

Comment: Well yes, but to start argueing on this, one might better define "*safe*" before. @Lundin

Comment: Safe as in "known to cause bugs, poorly-defined behavior and program crashes"? I can't think of many less safe functions in the C language.

Comment: @Lundin: If having defined "*unsafe*" like you just did in your comment I fully agree, `scanf()` is a blxxdy, dxxm, fxcking unsafe sxcker. I nearly ever and always refused playing with it. ...

Answer (score 5):

The main difference is that `gets` reads until EOF or `\n`, while `scanf("%s")` reads until any whitespace has been encountered. `scanf` also provides more formatting options, but at the same time it has worse type safety than `gets`.

Another big difference is that `scanf` is a standard C function, while `gets` has been removed from the language, since it was both superfluous and dangerous: there was no protection against buffer overruns. The very same security flaw exists with scanf however, so ***neither of those two functions should be used in production code***.

You should always use `fgets`, the C standard itself even recommends this, see C11 K.3.5.4.1

> **Recommended practice**
>
> 6 The fgets function allows properly-written
>   programs to safely process input lines too long to store in the result
>   array. In general this requires that callers of fgets pay attention to
>   the presence or absence of a new-line character in the result array.
>   **Consider using fgets** (along with any needed processing based on
>   new-line characters) instead of gets_s.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Note: `scanf("%s")` reads in and discards any leading white-space and _then_ scans and saves non-white-space until a subsequent white-space or `EOF`.

Answer (score 4):

`gets` -    Reads characters from stdin and stores them as a string.

`scanf` - Reads data from stdin and stores them according to the format specified int the `scanf` statement like `%d`, `%f`, `%s`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There are several. One is that gets() will only get character string data. Another is that gets() will get only one variable at a time. scanf() on the other hand is a much, much more flexible tool. It can read multiple items of different data types.

In the particular example you have picked, there is not much of a difference.

Answer (score 3):

**gets:->**

> `gets()` reads a line from stdin into the buffer pointed to  by  `s`  until either a terminating newline or EOF, which it replaces with a null byte (`'\0'`).

BUGS:->

> Never use `gets()`. Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many  characters  `gets()` will  read,  and  because `gets()` will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use. It has  been  used  to  break  computer security.  Use `fgets()` instead.

**scanf:->**

> The `scanf()` function reads input from the standard input stream stdin;

BUG:->

> Some times scanf makes boundary problems when deals with array and string concepts.

Comment: Please state the source if you are quoting something, and use quote formatting.

Answer (score 2):

In case of `scanf` you need that format mentioned, unlike in gets. So in `gets` you enter charecters, strings, numbers and spaces.

In case of `scanf` , you input ends as soon as a white-space is encountered.

But then in your example you are using '%s' so, neither `gets()` nor `scanf()` that the strings are valid pointers to arrays of sufficient length to hold the characters you are sending to them. Hence can easily cause an buffer overflow.

Tip: use `fgets()` , but that all depends on the use case

Answer (score 0):

The concept that scanf does not take white space is completely wrong. If you use this part of code it will take white white space also :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char name[25];  
printf("Enter your name :\n");
scanf("%[^\n]s",name);
printf("%s",name);
return 0;
}
```

Where the use of new line will only stop taking input. That means if you press enter only then it will stop taking inputs.

So, there is basically no difference between scanf and gets functions. It is just a tricky way of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` is much more flexible tool while `gets()` only gets one variable at a time.

Answer (score -1):

gets() is unsafe, for example: char str[1]; gets(str)
if you input more then the length, it will end with SIGSEGV.
if only can use gets, use malloc as the base variable.

Comment: As others mentioned, yes, it's unsafe to use `gets()`, but: *if you input more then the length* err, what? How would you ever input the length of a "string" in C?  You seem to be mixing up something here.