# Differences between gets(str) and scanf("%s", str)

Tags: scanf, c-strings, gets

What are the differences between `gets(str)` and `scanf("%s", str)` where str is a character array? Can you please explain with example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between gets and scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602608/whats-the-difference-between-gets-and-scanf)

Comment: Here's one similarity: they're both dangerous, in that neither can avoid overflowing the array if there's more input than expected.

Answer (score 0):

The basic difference between `scanf()` and `gets()` can be seen here:

[image]

For more: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-scanf-and-gets-in-c/

Thanks.